# SQL SERVER - how can I rollback "use [MASTER]" query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I accidentally ran query Change authentication mode (T-SQL) in sql server:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
     N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer',
     N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 1
GO
```

Now I can't work with SQL SERVER.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change it back using below code:

```
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite 
    N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
    N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', 
    N'LoginMode', 
    REG_DWORD, 
    2; -- only difference is right here
```

You have changed authentication mode to windows only. So now you have to log in using windows account then you can change the authentication mode to mixed mode again. Or you can edit your registry to do so. Please check below link:

https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/sql-server-authentication-mode.html